# Who is "Peter" in this sentence?

Tags: american-english, history

This is an excerpt from the self help book "Pushing To The Front" by Orison Swett Marden under a chapter entitled "Dare":

> As the strongest man has a weakness somewhere, so the greatest hero is a coward somewhere. **Peter** was courageous enough to draw his sword to defend his Master, but he could not stand the ridicule and the finger of scorn of the maidens in the high priest's hall, and he actually denied even the acquaintance of the Master he had declared he would die for.

I know this is not a grammar question, but I need to know who is 'Peter'. I'm not familiar with history of west.

Thanks

Comment: The necessary clue is in ***he actually denied even the acquaintance of the Master***. If you could make the necessary mental leap to realise that capitalised ***Master*** there refers to ***Jesus Christ***, you could have asked Google ***who denied christ*** (fortunately, Google doesn't care about capitalisation! :) I'm seriously impressed with how good Google is getting with "natural language queries" though. When ***I*** typed that in, I got the answer loud and clear (complete with link to Wikipedia's "Denial of Peter").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Peter, one of the disciples of Jesus. She is referencing the Bible, specifically Matthew 26:51-54 and Matthew 26:69-75. One source is here: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+26&version=AMP

Comment: Saint Peter. Often called Simon Peter. Note the capitalisation of 'Master', which is usually used about Jesus.